# How to not plot zero values in a bar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that looks like so [image] but I dont want bars with zero values to be plotted at all to condense the plot.
The code to make the plot looks like

```
PlotBar <- function(df, title){
  ggplot(df, aes(y = value, x = Role, fill = variable))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.75, position = "dodge")+
    labs(fill = "Gender")+
    ylab("Number of staff")+
    xlab("")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#e1251b","#1e1e1c"), name = "Gender", labels = c("Women","Men"))+
    
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),text=element_text(size=21))+
    ggtitle(title)
}
```

Comment: Filter your data before plotting. Hard to be more specific without a reproducible example.

Comment: Maybe `is.na(x) <- x == 0`. This will make zeros `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

R graphics instructions generally remove `NA` values before plotting. This is the case with `ggplot2`'s geoms like `geom_bar` and `geom_col`.

So the main step is the following, using function `is.na<-`:

```
is.na(df1$count) <- df1$count == 0
```

Alternatively,

```
df1$count[df1$count == 0] <- NA
```

And then the plot itself is pretty standard.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, count, fill = gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Women = 'red', Men = 'black')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

**Test data creation code.**

```
set.seed(2020)

x <- rep(sprintf('Label %02d', 1:10), each = 2)
x <- factor(x)
count <- sample(20)
count[sample(20, 4)] <- 0
gender <- rep(c('Women', 'Men'), 10)
gender <- factor(gender, levels = c('Women', 'Men'))
df1 <- data.frame(x, count, gender)
```

Comment: thanks, that does change the 0 values to NA, but still plotting those bars.
My code for that plot is in my edit

Comment: @Adam You're right. If you plot `na.omit(df1)` as the `data` argument, the bars with `NA`'s will be fatter. Give me some time, I will think about this.

Comment: I just used example_melt[!(rowSums(is.na(example_melt))),] and it worked